# Pyopengl Blackscreen

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, opengl-compat

While running [this sample code](https://stackabuse.com/brief-introduction-to-opengl-in-python-with-pyopengl/#codingexercise) on a GPU with OpenGL 3.1 support, the Pyopengl 3.1.5 (Python 3.8 & Windows10 Pro-64bit) window shows a **Black Screen**.

There are a few things missing in the sample code.
1. No color is specified for fragcolor.
2. Integer values are provided as inputs for `glVetex2f()`, instead of floats.
On rectifying the above issues and running the code, **the screen is still Black.**

# Script

```
import OpenGL
from OpenGL.GL import *
from  OpenGL.GLUT import * 
from OpenGL.GLU import * 
import io
print("Imports successful!")

w, h = 500,500

def poly_shape():     
    glBegin(GL_QUADS) 
    glColor4f(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)
    glVertex2f(100.0, 100.0)
    glVertex2f(200.0, 100.0) 
    glVertex2f(200.0, 200.0) 
    glVertex2f(100.0, 200.0) 
    glEnd()

def showScreen():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) # Remove everything from screen (i.e. displays all white)
    glLoadIdentity() # Reset all graphic/shape's position
    poly_shape() # Draw function call
    glutSwapBuffers()

#------
glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA) # Set the display mode to be colored
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500)   # Set the w and h of your window
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)   # Set the position at which this windows should appear
wind = glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Coding Practice") # Set a window title
glutDisplayFunc(showScreen)
glutIdleFunc(showScreen) # Keeps the window open
glutMainLoop()  # Keeps the above created window displaying/running in a loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the  [sample code](https://stackabuse.com/brief-introduction-to-opengl-in-python-with-pyopengl/#codingexercise)  ,the code for Mvp (Model-View-Projection) matrix was missing .On adding it under the ShowScreen() function,the draw call(square in this case) render's in the viewport .

[image: Screen rendering with Immediate Mode glsl script]

```
import OpenGL
from OpenGL.GL import *
from  OpenGL.GLUT import * 
from OpenGL.GLU import * 
import io
print("Imports successful!")


w, h = 500,500


def draw_shape():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS) 
    glColor4f(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)
    glVertex2f(100.0, 100.0)
    glVertex2f(200.0, 100.0) 
    glVertex2f(200.0, 200.0) 
    glVertex2f(100.0, 200.0) 
    glEnd() 
    glFlush()

def showScreen():
    glViewport(0, 0, 500, 500)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0, 500, 500, 0, -1, 1)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) # Remove everything from screen (i.e. displays all white)
    glLoadIdentity() # Reset all graphic/shape's position

    draw_shape() # Draw function

    glutSwapBuffers()

#---Section 3---
glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA) # Set the display mode to be colored
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500)   # Set the w and h of your window
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)   # Set the position at which this windows should appear
wind = glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Coding Practice") # Set a window title


glutDisplayFunc(showScreen)
glutIdleFunc(showScreen) # Keeps the window open
glutMainLoop()  # Keeps the above created window displaying/running in a loop*
```